# Getting "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection." error while using SqlQuery command

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to parameterize a dynamic query and run it using SqlQuery method in Entity Framework code first.

The first time I execute SqlQuery it works as expected so I am sure there is nothing wrong with query or parameters but immediately I execute the same command with the same parameters second time and I get this error

> "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection."

Since I am already using `ToList()` method here, I have no idea what the cause could be!

Here is the simulated code.

```
using (var context = Common.GetDbContext())
   {
        var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

         //populating parameters here...

         var sqlQuery = "Select * from MyTable where UserId=@p1 and And Active=@p2";

         // first time
         var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>(sqlQuery, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
         //second time
         result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>(sqlQuery, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: You have to create a new SqlParameter instances for each Query

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi SqlParameter is clonable. Try this:

```
result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ResultType>(sqlQuery, parameters.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToArray()).ToList();
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338957%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Do not know why visual studio could not recognize the x.Clone() method. so I changed it to Select(x => ((ICloneable)x).Clone()).ToArray()).ToList()  and it works like a charm.